# Obfuscate all but last 4 characters in string

Tags: javascript, regex

I got this regular expression replacing all but the last 4 characters in a string of digits:

`'1234567890'.replace(/\d(?=\d{4})/g, 'X'); // "XXXXXX7890"`

However, it only works for digits. I want it to match any alpha numeric character including spaces. I tried replacing the `/d` meta character with `/w` (in both places) but it doesn't work.

Can you help?

Comment: It’s `\d` and `\w`, not `/d` or `/w`.

Comment: Note that \w includes underscore, which you didn't mention wanting to match.

Comment: Actually, to match any char, you may use `[^]`, `[\s\S]`, `[\w\W]`, `[\D\d]`  or `.` (with the ECMAScript 2018 `s` modifier). Use `.replace(/.(?=.{4})/g, 'X')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to select both /w and a literal space so `(\w| )`. `|` is like an `OR`, where you're telling regex to select a word character or a space

Using your regex it would be: `'1234567890'.replace(/(\w| )(?=(\w| ){4})/g, 'X')`

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks @naguib

Comment: You can also use [\w ] instead of (\w| ) since both sides of the alternation  represent single characters.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `\w`

```
'123HGHJK90'.replace(/[\w ](?=[\w ]{4})/g, 'X');
```